# Which development toolset should I use for an Android slate?

Tags: android

I haven't looked at Android for a year or more, now (Oct 2011) I want to develop something for an Android slate.

What's the best IDE/GUI designer/debugger?

Is it still the Eclipse plug-in? Or is there something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [it's still the Eclipse plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#InstallingADT).

Comment: +1 Thanks. I'll leave this open for a few hours, then award you the answer if no one comes up with something better (like  NetBeans plugin (ymmv ;-))

Answer (score 0):

I like NetBeans... before today's morning, in any case:)